# Projection declaration in dojox.geo.openlayers possible?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system, dojo

I am trying to integrate some maps of my own into the dojox charting demo and I had success in exporting a shapefile (externally, i.e. with my own parser) to the dojo JSON map format. The map is in epsg:3035 (LAEA/ETRS89) and it looks distorted in dojo. It might be either a problem with my parser or with dojo. Does the OpenLayers integration in dojox allow for the declaration of the projection like in a "real" OpenLayers map, like in this example:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map("map", {
            controls: [
                //new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MouseDefaults(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()],
            maxExtent:
                new OpenLayers.Bounds(-20037508.34,-20037508.34,
                                       20037508.34, 20037508.34),
            numZoomLevels: 18,
            maxResolution: 156543,
            units: 'meters',
            projection: "EPSG:3035"} );
```

Or is it handled "as is" (e.g. lat/lon (epsg:4326)) which would mean, my parser is the problem?

I already searched the web for an answer but to no avail. Can you point me in the right direction?